# Solução de exceções ServiceException e Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven, jdbc

Esta ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> ServiceException e Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec?

Já mudei o nome do provider de org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence para org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider mas mesmo assim o erro persiste, vi também de inserir esse código na url de conexão: jdbc:mysql://hostname/databaseName?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC porém não sei aonde que ela fica... como faço para resolver?! Sou novo nessa parte de Java e procurei de tudo e nada

Abaixo segue o arquivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.victor</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-exemplo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>hibernate-jpa-exemplo</name>
</project>
```

META.INF > persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.victor.hibernate.modelo.Empregado</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Empregado.java

```
package br.victor.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

@Entity
@Table
public class Empregado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length = 4, nullable = false)
    private Long codigo;
    @Column(length = 150)
    private String nome;
    @Column(length = 150)
    private String sobrenome;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;

    ///constructors + getters & setters...

}
```

e a classe principal, TestarEmpregado.java:

```
package br.victor.hibernate.teste;

import br.victor.hibernate.modelo.Empregado;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Vickz
 */
public class TestarEmpregado {

    //@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    private static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static void main (String [] args){

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        List<Empregado> empregados = (List<Empregado>) em.createQuery("FROM Empregado").getResultList();
        System.out.println("Nesse banco de dados há: " + empregados.size() + " Empregados. ");

    }

}
```

Verifiquei tudo e soluções para esse caso e não consigo sair do lugar, estou quebrando minha cabeça nesse projeto que vendo parece relativamente simples porém ainda não me familiarizei com as outputs do Hibernate e do Maven dai estou caindo nessa linha de erro:

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building hibernate-jpa-exemplo 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ hibernate-jpa-exemplo ---
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Persistence
    ...]
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste]
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root}
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mar 19, 2017 6:14:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.victor.hibernate.teste.TestarEmpregado.main(TestarEmpregado.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora oficial do Brasil' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:69)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Hora oficial do Brasil' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:293)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2399)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1739)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    ... 34 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.897s
Finished at: Sun Mar 19 06:14:07 BRT 2017
Final Memory: 6M/116M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project hibernate-jpa-exemplo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao utilizar versões do *driver* `mysql-connector-java` superiores a 6.0, você precisa informar a propriedade `serverTimezone` com o valor desejado na sua `javax.persistence.jdbc.url`.

Altere isso:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste"/>
```

Para isso:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo"/>
```

#### Edit:

Olhando suas configurações, encontrei alguns outros problemas:

Existem múltiplas versões de uma mesma dependência no seu `pom.xml`. Remova todas as dependências do seu `pom.xml` e adicione apenas essas duas:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

No seu arquivo `persistence.xml`, remova a linha:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

E altere a linha:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

Para

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect"/>
```

Na sua classe `TestarEmpregado` utilize uma `TypedQuery` mudando a linha:

```
List<Empregado> empregados = (List<Empregado>) em.createQuery("FROM Empregado").getResultList();
```

Para:

```
List<Empregado> empregados = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Empregado e", Empregado.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: Fiz esse procedimento e finalmente conseguiu dar certo e eliminar a saída do Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec graças a Deus!! Agora só estou com o output gerando as exceptions: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet, Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'teste.empregado' doesn't exist, esses ele deu logo após ter criado a tabela e "setado" o select... inseri o javassist e nada mudou

Comment: Que devo fazer para corrigir? O banco já foi criado no MySQL manualmente e estou tentando inserir a tabela por esse código

Comment: @VictorG. Editei minha resposta com mais alguns procedimentos. Realize-os, e veja se resolvem o problema.

Comment: Boa!!! Deu tudo certo aqui e está compilando certinho @Felipe-Marinho!!, eu acredito que o Maven se confundiu na hora de baixar as dependências pois percebi que eu repeti naquela do 'org.hibernate' e o 'javax.persistence', nesse caso da TypedQuery esse: 'SELECT e FROM Empregado' equivale a aquela query no MySQL né: 'SELECT * FROM Empregado'? e o 'Empregado.class' a chamada da entidade criada? Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @VictorG. Sim, a JPQL `SELECT e FROM Empregado e` é equivalente ao seguinte SQL `SELECT * FROM Empregado`. O `Empregado.class` indica qual classe vai retornar a `TypedQuery`, a classe retornada não precisa ser uma `@Entity`. Você pode ler mais sobre `TypedQuery` e outras formas de realizar consultas [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/consultas-fortemente-tipadas-com-jpa/).

Answer (score 0):

resolvi o erro

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project

alterando / adicionando informacoes nesse linha

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo"/>
```